# PHP session variable not working in two pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

This is my first page.I just can't get my variables to the next page index.php ($_SESSION['admin_email']). The variable assignment works fine on the first page,  in index.php it always redirected to login.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include_once('../_inc/_class/Users.php');
$dbUsers = new Users();
$uname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$upass =  md5($_POST['password']);
if($uname != "" && $upass != "") {
   $user = $dbUsers->selectAll("`password` = '".$upass."' and `email` = '".$uname."' and user_type = 'admin'", "1", "");
    /*print_r($user);*/
    if(!empty($user) && $user[0]->email == $uname && $user[0]->password == $upass) {
        $_SESSION['admin_email'] = $user[0]->email;

        /*var_dump($_SESSION['admin_email']);*/
    }   
    else {
        $_SESSION = array();        
        session_destroy();      
    }

}
die(header('Location:../index.php'));
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_email'])) {
    die(header('Location:./login.php'));
}

?>
```

Comment: on the new page, do a `print_r($_SESSION);` to find out more information

Comment: Are you sure you are not accidentally using `session_destroy()` in the else part of your if statement?

Comment: Are you sure your login script is not going through the else portion of the if?       try placing a die() in the else....

Comment: print_r($_SESSION); it returns a null array

Comment: the login script is not going through the else portion.

Comment: First of all check whether code is going inside if statement or not. if it's not going inside the if statement then its not possible to set session according to your code then else statement will run and it destroy the all the session. So $_SESSION['admin_email'] will not be set if  if statement will false.

Comment: There's also a slim chance that you have cookies disabled on your browser in wich case session variables will not last a page refresh on default. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like login.php is residing inside a subfolder and not in the root folder where index.php reside.

You are setting the session value from the subfolder and if your php.ini settings or some `session_set_cookie_params()` in included class (Users.php) is setting the session path deliberately for that subfolder, it will make the session variable inaccessible outside that.

So try to add `session_set_cookie_params` and set the `$path` param to `/`

And then it will be available for the root folder and all subfolders inside that.

For more information check [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params)

Answer (score -3):

use

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();
```

instead of using plain

```
session_start();
```

Comment: look at OP's code properly. OP might be executing the `session_destroy` statement. Please confirm before giving a solution

Comment: @JP Kim please avoid  to give a single line answer, you could have posted in comment box, so use comment box for this type of answer